# Getting session counts, by source, from GA4 and BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've got GA4 pushing to BQ and I wanted to test some ideas, so I started with making sure my BiqQuery queries could duplicate (or at least get close to) what I see in the GA4 UI.

In GA4, I looked at the Traffic acquisition: Session source report and just looked at traffic with a source of 'google' for a specific date range. This is what I see:

[image: GA UI]

So just under 16k sessions for google during this timeframe.

I then ran this query to get session counts by source and just had it show me the results for Google:

```
WITH prep AS (
SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
    MAX((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'source')) AS source,
  FROM `disco-retina-319219.analytics_312878766.events_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20221112' AND '20221209'
group by
    user_pseudo_id,
    session_id)

SELECT
    COALESCE(source,'(direct)') AS source,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(user_pseudo_id,session_id)) AS sessions
FROM
    prep
WHERE source='google'
GROUP BY
    source
ORDER BY
    sessions desc
```

But it only shows 4,200 sessions.

I expected the results might be slightly off, but my BQ query is showing just over 4k sessions. Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. I'm getting a distinct list of the concatenated session ID and pseudo user ID; from what I've read this is the proper way to get a list of distinct sessions. I've verified that I am using the same date ranges in both (11/12/2022 - 12/9/2022) and that I hitting the proper table in BQ.

Comment: `user_pseudo_id` is often null, so `CONCAT(user_pseudo_id,session_id)` will be null also. Hence the Count Distinct will be underestimated